# How to detect or log (ubuntu 14.04) when Ruby forks the process?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, fork, trace

I'm trying to reduce the amount of forking our Ruby/Rails app does.  We shell out a lot with backticks, and each of these forks the entire process, which can cause a huge memory bloat.

I'm going through, identifying the ones that get called the most, and trying to replace them with code which achieves the same thing without making a shell call.  However, in some cases I suspect it might still be forking under the hood anyway.

Is there a way to detect or log whenever a process forks?  I'm using ubuntu 14.04.  A log would be ideal as I can then keep an eye on it when I run the amended code.

Comment: *...in some cases I suspect it might still be forking under the hood anyway*. Can you add more specifics on how you suspect this is happening? You mean you have a gem that you suspect calls `fork`? What is the real source of your suspicion?

Comment: @Casper If I was to give a specific example method you would be tempted to try to answer the specific question of whether that method does fork, which isn't what I want to know.  Let's just assume that it's **possible** that something might be forking - yes, in a gem for example - and that I want to try to detect when that happens.

Comment: Unless you're using a terrible OS, forking doesn't replicate your entire Rails instance; I suspect this is an X/Y problem where you are abusing your environment (which *does* get exported to children), relying on the shell rather than Kernel#system to call your external code directly, or calling too many long-lived processes. Even 10,000 subshells that write to standard output takes me less than 20 seconds of real time (mostly I/O); less than half that for commands that don't spawn a shell or write to the terminal.

Comment: If you really want to do this, you might be able to hook TracePoint to Kernel#system or Kernel#fork.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs all of the build-in shell-out commands in ruby do fork and replicate the process. CoW might significantly reduce the memory impact (is that what you mean?). the posix-spawn gem is the only way i know of to shell-out without forking